# Import Excel table rows as articles

Tags: articles, database

I have a different products organized in Excel file.

Every column means something - Title, Description, Weight, Price and so on.

Can I import them in Joomla in such a way, that every row is a new article?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Content Uploader Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/content-uploader-pro/) (or its free version).